Cannot Access Terracotta Management Server via Docker install
I am trying to setup a Terracotta server instance as a test case for using EHCache caching for a legacy Java project.  I have downloaded and installed the three terracotta packages below:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                COMMAND             CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
199088b58d5b   softwareag/terracotta-management-server:10.15.0.14   "./entrypoint.sh"   4 days ago   Up 4 days   0.0.0.0:9480->9480/tcp, :::9480->9480/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9889->9889/tcp, :::9889->9889/tcp   youthful_sinoussi
37c97b886a78   softwareag/sample-ehcache-client:10.15.0.14          "./entrypoint.sh"   4 days ago   Up 4 days                                                                                          caching-client
f9cc2b5d948c   softwareag/terracotta-server:10.15.0.14              "./entrypoint.sh"   4 days ago   Up 4 days   0.0.0.0:9410->9410/tcp, :::9410->9410/tcp                                              terracotta

I am unable to access either though.  The ports are properly mapped and I verified as such by shelling into the instances and observing the ports used via Netstat:
bteeter@qu1mtterra1001:~ > docker exec -it 199088b58d5b /bin/sh
~/terracotta/tms $ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9480            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18821383 
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18817765 

and
bteeter@qu1mtterra1001:~ > docker exec -it f9cc2b5d948c /bin/sh
~/terracotta/server $ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9410            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18809880 
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18807706 

If I try to load localhost:9480 or localhost:9480/tmc on the management server I get a 404 error.
I always get 404's or permission errors on the terracotta server hitting 9410.
I get the same errors if I try the ports via the host machine.
What am I missing here?  Its nearly impossible to figure out what to tweak as these docker images have really no documentation - and the Terracotta documentation is very variable depending on what version you read.
What I tried is above, what I am expecting is to see the Terracotta Management Console, with which I can validate the server is running.
